# Visa to work in European Union

Tags: job-search, job-offer, recruitment, visa, europe

I'm a non-EU citizen. Got an email asking to confirm whether I have a Visa to work in European Union without restrictions or sponsorships?

Does it mean that I have to get the Visa before applying for a Job in EU?

Comment: Go on the appropriate EU website and go through the requirements for getting a visa that allows to to work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is asking about EU work visa requirements  - a government regulations specific question.

Comment: Not asking about the requirements. Just want to know whether I need to get the Visa before the job or employer will manage all the prerequisites?

Comment: If you want to know whether the employer will manage all the prerequisites, then ask the employer. What part of asking whether you need to get the Visa before the job - that question is EU regulation-specific don't you understand?

Comment: The plain language of the letter asks you to confirm whether you have a visa that permits you to work without restrictions or sponsorships in the EU. Your answer to this request to confirm is either 'yes' or 'no'

Answer (score 2):

There are two options here;

-The company you are about to work may sponsor you for your visa.

-The company hire people who has already grant/visa before starting to work.

Either way the country expects you to have a valid documents before arrival and working there. For further information get advice from the country's information service and the company.

Answer (score 2):

> Does it mean that I have to get the Visa before applying for a Job in
>   EU?

It generally means that you'll need to have the ability to *work* without being sponsored by the hiring company.

If you have the appropriate citizenship already, or if you already have the appropriate Visa, then it will certainly be easier for you to be interviewed.

But if you are on the path toward gaining citizenship or will otherwise have the ability to work unsponsored at some specific point in the near future, then it will likely be possible to apply and be accepted conditionally.

If you aren't already on that path, most likely this company wouldn't bother talking with you, and won't accept your application. Their email is suggesting that this particular company isn't willing to sponsor you. Answer their email honestly and quickly, and you'll soon learn what they are willing to do for you, or not.

Comment: Google, Amazon AWS and IBM are examples of companies that will ask about visa status and sponsor a candidate for a work visa in the US but I am fairly sure that candidate has to be good enough i.e. outstanding to justify the paperwork. Have no  idea how things work out in EU.

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan It depends on the country and the job. Some countries have a simplified, fast track process for knowledge workers. In the Netherlands, for example, the knowledge worker residence permit application process takes only two weeks but requires a minimum salary and the employer must apply. The regular visa/residence permit process is often obnoxious, similar to the H1B in the US, and it would be hard to find a company willing to sponsor someone through that.